# enumitem option that puts space between bottom of list and next line

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

The code below illustrates my problem.    I've killed off a lot of the space that separate lists, but if I have a line of text immediately after the list, the line gets pushed up so that it overlaps the last list item.      I can fix this problem by adding `\setlist[enumerate, 1]{after=\vspace*{10pt}}` but this adds a space that I don't want if there's *no* line immediately below the list.    Obviously I can kludge fix it by adding spaces manually, but there *has to be* a way to add a parameter to the `\setlist` specification that resolves this problem.       Thanks for any suggestions.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\parindent=0 pt
\parskip=12 pt
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\def\myTopSep{-8pt}
\def\myItemSep{0ex}
\def\myParSep{0ex}
\def\myParTopSep{0ex}
\setlist[enumerate]{topsep=\myTopSep,itemsep=\myItemSep,partopsep=\myParTopSep,parsep=\myParSep}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{enumerate}
    \item one
    \item two
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item three
        \item four
    \end{enumerate}
    This is a line
    \item one
    \item two
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item three
        \item four
    \end{enumerate}
    \item one
    \item two
\end{enumerate}
\par
Now I'm going to add  \verb+\setlist[enumerate, 1]{after=\vspace*{10pt}}+ etc
\par
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\setlist[enumerate, 1]{after=\vspace*{10pt}}
\setlist[enumerate, 2]{after=\vspace*{10pt}}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{enumerate}
    \item one
    \item two
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item three
        \item four
    \end{enumerate}
    This is a line
    \item one
    \item two
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item three
        \item four
    \end{enumerate}
    \item one
    \item two
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `\def\myTopSep{-8pt}`. Put differently, if you were to set `\def\myTopSep{0pt}`, there wouldn't be a need for `after=\vspace*{10pt}` (or after=\vspace{10pt}`). Please clarify.

Comment: @Mico, I'm sorry my MWE was a bit too minimal.    Because I really hat the default indentation that latex does, my standard preamble begins with `\parindent=0 pt
\parskip=12 pt`   which I really don't want to give up.    So my `\def\myTopSep{-8pt}` serves to offset this `\parskip` before I start to enumerate.   I can see that this is a real problem, since I'm trying to have my cake and eat it, but given this, do you see a solution?

Comment: Please see the answer I posted earlier today. I think I found a solution. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the fundamental issue is that you've set `\parskip=12 pt` or, more LaTeX-y, `\parskip=1\baselineskip`. IMNSHO, if that's the right value for other parts of your document, it should be the right value for list environments such as `enumerate` and `itemize` as well.

If you really must annihilate the non-zero value of `\parskip` around list environments, you could set the options `before=\vspace{-1\baselineskip}` and `after=\vspace{-1\baselineskip}` along with `nosep` for level-1 list environments and just `nosep` for level-2 (and above) list environments.

Aside: setting the option `nosep` must be easier than setting `topsep`, `itemsep`, `partopsep`, and `parsep` to `0pt`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\parindent=0pt
\parskip=1\baselineskip
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{nosep,
                      before=\vspace{-1\baselineskip},
                      after =\vspace{-1\baselineskip}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{nosep}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-4] % filler text
\begin{enumerate}
    \item one
    \item two
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item three
        \item four
    \end{enumerate}
    This is a line
    \item one
    \item two
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item three
        \item four
    \end{enumerate}
    \item one
    \item two
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[1][5-8] % filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much indeed!